# Multiple cameras assigned different depths

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

A similar question was asked in the past, but the new version of Unity, does not solve my problems. When setting multiple cameras with different depth, they handle different layer. But when I add the shader blur, the second chamber, which handles only one layer, this blur is added to all elements. Why is it, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying the texture, depth and alignment of the behavior of the camera changes. For example, a shader camera should be in the background, with the settings skoboh, because the main can monitor everything and retain only the second shader setting depth only. Sorry for bad english.

[image]

[image]